# Convert currency string to decimal?

Tags: c#, .net, type-conversion

### Objective

Sort a `string` that is displaying currency data like this `$1,995.94` numerically in a set of data.

### Code

I'm currently using the below code sample to convert the `string` value to `decimal` so that I can sort it properly.

```
if (sortBy == "checkAmount")
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var c in Convert.ToString(p.GetType().GetProperty(sortBy).GetValue(p, null)))
    {
        if (!char.IsDigit(c) && c != '.') { continue; }
        sb.Append(c);
    }
    return Convert.ToDecimal(sb.ToString());
}
else
{
    return p.GetType().GetProperty(sortBy).GetValue(p, null);
}
```

### Problem

What's a better way of doing this? It works, and that's cool, but it's not very elegant.

### Final Solution

The [answer provided by Servy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14162357/1011722) **works as expected**, and I used that implementation for a while, but a colleague and I found an even better way so I'm documenting it here. ***BTW, I ended up using this solution in the end.***

```
decimal.Parse(input, NumberStyles.AllowCurrencySymbol | NumberStyles.Number);
```

Comment: First off, separate out the string parsing from the business logic.  Have a method `ParseString` that takes a `string` and returns a `decimal` instead of mixing it with a bunch of logic for getting the string to be parsed.  Next, you can use a regex, such as `^[\d.]+` (untested) instead of your loop.

Comment: Oh, and since you have "working" code this should probably be on code review, not SO.

Comment: @Servy, I'm working on that RegEx right now.

Comment: @Servy, I got this working `[-\d.]+`, but will that `-` cause an issue? I just wanted to make sure that I got negative numbers. I realized that I had missed those in the current algorithm.

Comment: Well, your current code doesn't handle negative numbers, and I replicated that behavior.  You could add the `-` to the regex and it would work, yes.  I'd put it outside of the `[]` so that it needs to be at the start (as you would expect in a real number) and not somewhere in the middle.

Comment: @Servy, yeah I realized I was missing negative numbers simply by posting this question. LOL

Comment: @Servy, please see my update. I am leaving your answer as the accepted answer, but a colleague and I found an even better way. Check it out.

Comment: The NumberStyles namespace is: System.Globalization.NumberStyles.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is a method that most closely resembles the code you've provided

```
public static decimal Parse(string input)
{
    return decimal.Parse(Regex.Replace(input, @"[^\d.]", ""));
}
```

Here is an option that will support negative numbers, and will stop if it finds a second period value, thus reducing the number of strings it returns that are not valid `decimal` values.  It also has a few other modifications not seen in the OP to handle additional cases your current code doesn't.

```
public static decimal Parse(string input)
{
    return decimal.Parse(Regex.Match(input, @"-?\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*(\.\d+)?").Value);
}
```

Comment: Beware of this solution, particularly the 2nd part.  It doesn't handle all cases, and there is a serious bug if the input is -5000 it evaluates to -500.

Answer (score 36):

How about this, but only works for one string value. So you need to get your string `split` by `$` and then do the conversion while saving into the `array` or `list`

```
 using System.Globalization;
    //rest of your code

          string str = "$50,550.20";
          decimal decval;
          bool convt = decimal.TryParse(str, NumberStyles.Currency,
            CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat, out decval);
          if (convt) 
          Console.WriteLine(decval);
          Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: See [my other comment here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14162357/convert-currency-string-to-decimal#comment19619663_14162396).  Your code would say it couldn't produce a valid value if given invalid chars at the end of a string, his code make an attempt to get as much of a number as possible.  Even if it's not desirable, that's not equivalent code.

Comment: Thanks for showing the flaws @Servy much appreciated. Reading your comment.

Comment: @bonCodigo You really hit on the proper way to process currency. While it doesn't mimic the OPs method *exactly* it shows the proper way to do it. The OPs example "accepts" malformed currency values such as `$1995.,94`, or even `$abc.123,456`. There is no *standard* way to interpret these strings as numbers, which is why there is a built in standard of parsing currency. +1

Comment: @NominSim thank you very helpful as you gave examples. :) My understanding was that OP has a string e.g. `$1,234.50$23456.99 $345.88` and so on.. But I realize a `regex` will strip the numbers including a '$' `.` and then convert to `decimal`.

Comment: used this solution referencing specific culture formats.  Fx.  bool convt = decimal.TryParse(amount, NumberStyles.Currency, CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("da-DK").NumberFormat, out decimal decval);

Answer (score 17):

Here is a simpler solution:

```
    public static decimal ToDecimal(this string str)
    {
        return decimal.Parse(str, NumberStyles.Currency);
    }
```

and the unit test:

```
    [Test]
    public void ToDecimal_Convert_String_To_Decimal()
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(1234M, "1234".ToDecimal());
        Assert.AreEqual(-1234.56M, "$(1,234.56)".ToDecimal());
        Assert.AreEqual(1234.56M, "$1,234.56".ToDecimal());
    }
```

Comment: More optimised than Regex, though not compatible with other currency symbols than CurrentCulture.

Answer (score 12):

```
decimal amount = decimal.Parse("$123,456.78",
NumberStyles.AllowCurrencySymbol |
NumberStyles.AllowThousands |
NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint);
```

Comment: Providing an explanation of the elements of your answer and why it is better and more elegant would make this a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

**works for all culture:**

```
var d = decimal.Parse("$497.7", NumberStyles.Currency, CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("us-US").NumberFormat);    

Console.WriteLine(d);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static decimal ToDecimalFromStringDecimalOrMoneyFormattedDecimal(this string s)
{
    try
    {
        return decimal.Parse(s);
    }
    catch
    {
        var numberWithoutMoneyFormatting = Regex.Replace(s, @"[^\d.-]", "");
        return decimal.Parse(numberWithoutMoneyFormatting);
    }
}

[Test]
public void Test_ToDecimalFromStringDecimalOrMoneyFormattedDecimal()
{
    Assert.That("$ 500".ToDecimalFromStringDecimalOrMoneyFormattedDecimal() == (decimal)500);
    Assert.That("R -500".ToDecimalFromStringDecimalOrMoneyFormattedDecimal() == (decimal)-500);
    Assert.That("-$ 500".ToDecimalFromStringDecimalOrMoneyFormattedDecimal() == (decimal)-500);
    Assert.That("P 500.90".ToDecimalFromStringDecimalOrMoneyFormattedDecimal() == (decimal)500.9);
    Assert.That("$ -50 0,090,08.08".ToDecimalFromStringDecimalOrMoneyFormattedDecimal() == (decimal)-50009008.08);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can try to use [`decimal.TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.tryparse?view=net-6.0) to cast the currency string value to a decimal number.

- [NumberStyles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.numberstyles?view=net-6.0)：use `NumberStyles.Currency` which indicates that all styles except `AllowExponent` and `AllowHexSpecifier` are used. This is a composite number style.
- [CultureInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo?view=net-6.0)： we need to set the right culture of currency which align with your currency value.

For this example, `$20,000.00` is USA currency we can try to use  `English (USA)` for that, on the other hand `20,000.00€` is euro currency we can try to use  `English (Ireland)` that uses the euro currency.

```
decimal.TryParse("20,000.00€", NumberStyles.Currency ,CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-IE"), out var euro);
Console.WriteLine(euro);
decimal.TryParse("$20,000.00", NumberStyles.Currency ,CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-us"), out var dollar);
Console.WriteLine(dollar);
```

[c# online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kxb0QH)

Answer (score -1):

Here is code to convert such kind of strings:

10,239,13
3345.33
111,23

```
decimal.Parse(document.Price.Replace(".", ","), CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ru-RU")); //some culture with coma digits separator
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help] useful when it comes to [answer]. Your answer has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: Some constructive? I copied my code from my project to help people. p.s. decimal.Parse(document.Price.Replace(".", ","), CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fr-FR"))