# Convert.ToDecimal Fails and says Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have this view model class with the price property.

The problem is if user enter value `$200,150.90` it is not formatted and send to controller.

What could be the problem with default model formatter for decimal?

```
public ItemViewModel
{

public string Name {get;set;}
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:c}")]
[RegularExpression(@"^\$?([0-9]{1,3},([0-9]{3},)*[0-9]{3}|[0-9]+)(.[0-9][0-9])?$"
ErrorMessage = "Enter a valid money value. 2 Decimals only allowed")]
public decimal? Price{ get; set; }
}
```

In View

```
@model ItemViewModel

@Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.Price)
```

In Controller

```
public ActionResult Save(ItemViewModel model)
{

 // model.Price is always null, even if it has value $200,150.90
}
```

I have registered this decimal model binder in `Global.asax`

```
   ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(decimal?), new DecimalModelBinder());

   public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext,
        ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        ValueProviderResult valueResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider
            .GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
        ModelState modelState = new ModelState { Value = valueResult };
        object actualValue = null;
        try
        {
            actualValue = Convert.ToDecimal(valueResult.AttemptedValue,
                CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
        }
        catch (FormatException e)
        {
            modelState.Errors.Add(e);
        }

        bindingContext.ModelState.Add(bindingContext.ModelName, modelState);
        return actualValue;
    }
```

Error in Model Binder `Input string was not in a correct format`

```
 Convert.ToDecimal("$200,150.90",CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
```

Comment: What culture is being used during parsing?

Comment: @JonSkeet, Checking this `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` in a controller shows `en-US`

Answer (score 0):

Added additional decimal conversion if the format is currency

Thanks to [Convert currency string to decimal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14162357/convert-currency-string-to-decimal)

```
 string currencyDisplayFormat=(bindingContext.ModelMetadata).DisplayFormatString;
 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(currencyDisplayFormat) 
                           && currencyDisplayFormat == "{0:c}")
 {
    actualValue = Decimal.Parse(valueResult.AttemptedValue,
                  NumberStyles.AllowCurrencySymbol | NumberStyles.Number, 
                  CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);

 }
 else
 {
        actualValue = Convert.ToDecimal(valueResult.AttemptedValue,
                        CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
 }
```