# How can I convert currency strings to numerical values?

Tags: string, powershell, currency

Is there a way to convert currency strings to floating values, for example:

```
$1,138.15
$ 29.10
$2,195.34
```

Should be converted to:

```
1138.15
29.10
2195.34
```

Some currency strings have space between the dollar sign and the dollar value.

I am doing this because I am extracting the cost values from PDFs (which are converted to txt files) and do arithmetic on them.  For example, a portion of text file looks like this:

```
Fixed Power

$1,138.15

General Admin Surcharge

$ 29.10

Customer Charge

$2,195.34
```

And my code looks like this:

```
$sourceFile = Get-Content $sourcePath\$($filenames[0]).txt

$fixedPower = $sourceFile[(
    Select-String `
        -Path $sourcePath\$($filenames[0]).txt `
        -Pattern "Fixed Power" `
        -List
).LineNumber + 1]

$generalAdminSurcharge = $sourceFile[(
    Select-String `
        -Path $sourcePath\$($filenames[0]).txt `
        -Pattern "General Admin Surcharge" `
        -List
).LineNumber + 1]

$customerCharge = $sourceFile[(
    Select-String `
        -Path $sourcePath\$($filenames[0]).txt `
        -Pattern "Customer Charge" `
        -List
).LineNumber + 1]
```

But those only extract the costs into string values.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$Test = '$1,138.15','$ 29.10','$2,195.34'

$Test |
 foreach { $_ -replace '[^0-9.]'}


1138.15
29.10
2195.34
```

If you want the trailing 0 you'll have to leave it as [string] until you do whaterver calculations you want with it.

Comment: ...or more succinctly, `$Test -replace '[^\d.]'`.

Answer (score 5):

You could do a Replace to remove whatever extra things you want gone from the string, and then cast it as a `[decimal]`

```powershell
[decimal]$customerCharge = $customerCharge -replace "(\$| |,)"
```

**Edit:** Of coarse mjolinor beat me to it, and did it better. Man he's good!

Answer (score 0):

Even though this post has an answer already, the answer does not handle negative values indicated by either `()` or `-`. Since this is the question that pops up when googling how to parse a currency string into a decimal value in PowerShell, I figured I would leave an update.

For brevity in the code examples, I am using the enum int value directly rather than the enum name.

[[System.Globalization.NumberStyles]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.numberstyles?view=net-7.0#fields)

Instead of `383`, you should really be using:

```
[System.Globalization.NumberStyles]::Currency
```

Using `[decimal]::TryParse()` - method returns bool indicating status of parsing attempt, if successful, method returns `$True` and the reference variable is populated with the parsed value, otherwise the method returns `$False` and the reference variable is set to 0.

```
New-Variable -Name test -Force
$null = [decimal]::TryParse('-$ 1,200.20' , 383, (Get-Culture).NumberFormat, [ref]$test); $test
$null = [decimal]::TryParse('($ 1,200.20)', 383, (Get-Culture).NumberFormat, [ref]$test); $test
$null = [decimal]::TryParse('$1,200.20'   , 383, (Get-Culture).NumberFormat, [ref]$test); $test
$null = [decimal]::TryParse('$1200.20'    , 383, (Get-Culture).NumberFormat, [ref]$test); $test
$null = [decimal]::TryParse('$ 1200.2'    , 383, (Get-Culture).NumberFormat, [ref]$test); $test
$null = [decimal]::TryParse('$1200'       , 383, (Get-Culture).NumberFormat, [ref]$test); $test
```

Using `[decimal]::Parse()` - Either is successful, or throws an exception.

```
[decimal]::Parse('-$ 1,200.20' , 383, (Get-Culture).NumberFormat) # Returns '-1200.20'
[decimal]::Parse('($ 1,200.20)', 383, (Get-Culture).NumberFormat) # Returns '-1200.20'
[decimal]::Parse('$(1,200.20)' , 383, (Get-Culture).NumberFormat) # Returns '-1200.20'
[decimal]::Parse('$1,200.20'   , 383, (Get-Culture).NumberFormat) # Returns '1200.20'
[decimal]::Parse('$1200.20'    , 383, (Get-Culture).NumberFormat) # Returns '1200.20'
[decimal]::Parse('$ 1200.2'    , 383, (Get-Culture).NumberFormat) # Returns '1200.2'
[decimal]::Parse('$1200'       , 383, (Get-Culture).NumberFormat) # Returns '1200'
```

This answer was adapated from a similar answer for C#:
[Convert currency string to decimal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14162357/convert-currency-string-to-decimal)

Just a tip to future readers, if you can't find the answer to what you need under the PowerShell tag, try searching under C# / .NET. You'll likely be able to find the answer there, and then you can adapt the answer to use in PowerShell, which is how I came up with this answer.