# C#: Convert String with number and text to float

Tags: c#, .net

I am reading from an Excel file a column that represents price.
(These lines are in a loop).

```
dynamic tempPrice = (range.Cells[i, 15] as Excel.Range).Value2;
float price = (tempPrice == null) ? 0 : (float)tempPrice;
```

There are 3 possible cases:

- The cell might be empty (in this case I'm converting it to 0)
- The cell might contain a number.
- The cell might contain a string of a number and the currency name (e.g "140 USD", "140$" etc).

In the 3rd case (which breaks my code), how can I get only the number and convert it to float?

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14162357/convert-currency-string-to-decimal)

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code

```
float.Parse(tempPrice , NumberStyles.AllowCurrencySymbol | NumberStyles.Number);
```

Comment: TryParse is a much better method to use.

Answer (score 1):

When you try to parse values, you should always verifies at first if it can be parsed before parsing. Doing so, you can avoid any kind of error during the runtime.

Here's how you could do it ( you can find a similar way there : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/701df7da-17d8-41b5-b2d2-94b2be9c0191/floattryparse)

```
if(float.TryParse(tempPrice,NumberStyles.AllowCurrencySymbol, out value)
   {
    Console.WriteLine("Converted '{0}' to {1}.", tempPrice, value); 
   }
```

Hope it helps you !

Comment: If the answer that was provided helps you in any way or is actually was you were looking for, mark it as the answer so others will know in the future! :)

Comment: Thanks, This was mostly helpful, but "AllowCurrencySymbol" doesn't recognize all cases in this specific Excel file (the man who created it had many typing mistakes).

Comment: Try the logical OR and write NumberStyle.Number. It should work for about 99% of the case at the very least I think! Let me know if it helps you

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
float price;
if(!Single.TryParse(Regex.Replace(tempPrice, "\D+$", ""), out price)) {
  price = 0;
}
// if it doesn't enter the condition, then price will have the parsed float value.
```