# Selenium List Sort Order Comparison C#

Tags: c#, selenium

I have a typical web page that has check boxes to filter on and then there is a drop down to sort by low to high and high to low. The list/xpath code below returns 25 elements with varying prices.

What I want to do is assert that when I select the sort option from low to high, that my prices should look like $10, $10, $12, $15, etc. What is my next step here? It has been awhile since I have worked with list and my mind is drawing a blank.

I think I used Linq last time, sorted the results and ran a compare but after looking at this for three hours I have gone brain dead.

Suggestions?

```
        public List<string> GetInitialSortByPrice ()
        {
        List<String> item = new List<string>();
        IReadOnlyList<IWebElement> cells = 
        Browser.FindElements_byXpath("//h4[@class='price']");
        foreach (IWebElement cell in cells)
        {
            item.Add(cell.Text);
        }
        return item;
        }
```

Solution....

```
            List<String> item = new List<string>();
            IReadOnlyList<IWebElement> cells = 
            Browser.FindElements_byXpath("//h4[@class='price']");
            foreach (IWebElement cell in cells)
            {
                item.Add(cell.Text.Replace("$", ""));
            }
            List<decimal> listA = item.Select(s => 
            decimal.Parse(s)).ToList();
            List<decimal> listB = listA.OrderBy(x => x).ToList();

            Assert.IsTrue(listA.SequenceEqual(listB));
```

This was for the descending order:

```
            List<decimal> listB = listA.OrderByDescending(i => i).ToList();
```

Comment: Remove `$` from the entries. Parse them to `decimal` (so you have a `List<decimal>`) Then check that i`temsDecimal.OrderBy(z => z).SequenceEqual(ItemsDecimal)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert currency string to decimal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14162357/convert-currency-string-to-decimal)

Comment: Thanks All. I posted the solution in the question since it looked a little cleaner there. I need to clean that code up a bit but at least it is working.